# Confusion on order of group action on function

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\Gamma$ be a group and $\Gamma'\leq \Gamma$ be the subgroup. Let $Y$ be $\Gamma'$ module. Define induction $Ind^\Gamma_{\Gamma'}Y=<f:\Gamma\to Y\vert\forall\gamma\in\Gamma,\gamma'\in\Gamma',f(\gamma'\gamma)=\gamma'f(\gamma)>$ as abelian group generated by elements prescribed.

Then $\Gamma$ action on $Ind^\Gamma_{\Gamma'}$ is defined by $\gamma\in\Gamma, (\gamma f)(x)=f(x\gamma)$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ When I try to verify the group action for $\gamma_i\in\Gamma$ $[(\gamma_1\gamma_2)f](x)=f(x\gamma_1\gamma_2)$ and $(\gamma_1)[(\gamma_2)f]=\gamma_1(f(x\gamma_2))=f(x\gamma_2\gamma_1)$, I cannot have $(\gamma_1\gamma_2)f=\gamma_1(\gamma_2(f))$. Have I done something wrong? Neukirch defined $\Gamma$ action by $(\gamma f)(x)=f(\gamma x)$. Then I have no trouble to see $\Gamma$ action here by $(\gamma_1\gamma_2f)(x)=f(\gamma_1\gamma_2x)=\gamma_1(f(\gamma_2x))=\gamma_1((\gamma_2)f)(x)$

---

Per Arnaud Mortier's comment, I think I figured out what is wrong in my mind setting. $\gamma f(x)=f(x\gamma)$ is setting left action of $f$ to right action on $x$. $(\gamma\gamma' )f(x)=f(x\cdot(\gamma\gamma'))=f((x\gamma')\gamma)=\gamma f(x\gamma')=\gamma(\gamma' f)(x)$

For $\gamma f(x)=f(\gamma x)$(Neukirch's definition), I need $(\gamma\gamma')f(x)=\gamma(\gamma' f)(x)=\gamma' f(\gamma x)=f(\gamma'\gamma x)$. I need to change left action to right action again here.

Ref. Lectures on Algebraic Geometry by Gunter Harder 2.2.4 Exercise 7.

Comment: There is a notion of right action and left action, and the syntax should be adapted accordingly.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yes. That is what I thought. My guess is $Hom(-,Y)$ is contravariant. That is why you want right action turned into left action.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks for the hint. I think I figured it out.

Comment: Dear @user45765, In the derivation you have added there are two errors that cancel one another to give you the desired result. Namely the second and fourth equalities are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct computation to verify that $(\gamma_1\gamma_2)f=\gamma_1(\gamma_2f)$ goes as follows. Given $x\in\Gamma$, we have

$$((\gamma_1\gamma_2)f)(x)=f(x(\gamma_1\gamma_2))=f((x\gamma_1)\gamma_2)
=(\gamma_2 f)(x\gamma_1)=(\gamma_1(\gamma_2f))(x)\text{.}$$

Note also that in your definition of the induced $\Gamma$-module, you do not need to include "abelian group generated by [the] elements prescribed," because the indicated functions already form a group under pointwise addition (using the operation on $Y$) of functions.